# How to kill an Android activity which is called in same Activity for more than one time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have called one Activity to load the list of items, Based on item click i have created the same Activity to load the child data. This will happen X number of times based on the API response. Now when click the `Home Button` it should navigate to first Activity. Also when I click onBackPressed( ) method it should come back to previous state of that activity. But it is not navigate correctly.

Below I have mentioned the creating same activity code,

```
                Intent i1 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("activityCount", activityCount + 1);
                startActivity(i1);
```

Below I have mentioned the code in Home Icon method,

```
                if (activityCount > 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < activityCount; j++) {
                        SecondActivity = new SecondActivity();
                        SecondActivity.finish();
                    }
                }
                finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very incorect

```
SecondActivity = new SecondActivity();
SecondActivity.finish();
```

first line is creating `new` `SecondActivity`, next is finishing it. this instance was never visible and never called single own method of lifecycle (like e.g. `onCreate`), it isn't related at all to previously created and visible Activities (which are still in back stack) - just some local variable created only for killing it

instead of just calling `startActivity` consider using `startActivityForResult` (some doc [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)). don't override `onBackPressed`, currently visible `Activity` will close and then inside `onActivityResult` (called in prev instance of this `Activity`) check `activityCount` - if too high then just call `finish` and previous `Activity` will close, again calling `onActivityResult` of prev `Activity`, and so on. this way whole `Activity`s stack will close

PS. you may use [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) inside `onBackPressed` just before `super` or `finish` call for returning some data to previous `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the initial `Activity` number is 1 . Whenever you want to go to another `Activity` first check the number of current `Activity` and if it wasn't the first `Activity`, finish it before going to another `Activity`. In this way when you click on the back button, just the first `Activity` is on the stack and you'll see that.

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("activityCount", activityCount + 1);
startActivity(i1);

if(activityCount > 1)
 finish();
```

But in general, it's better to update List when you click on an item instead of creating a new `Activity`.